# Trying to aim the particles to camera while rotating and alert message on intersecting in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, webgl

I'm trying to create event handler on the particles, with alert message on a sphere, aiming always on the camera.
Something similar to [this demo](http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/worldwonders/) ( and making it to work on IE 9+ )

here is my code..
http://jsfiddle.net/praveenv29/cVnKV/11/

```
var renderer, projector;
var mouseX, mouseY, stats, container;
var objects = [];
var INTERSECTED;

var camera, scene, renderer, material, mesh, cont;

var w1 = 960;
var h1 = 700;

var halfWidth = w1 / 2;
var halfHeigth = h1 / 2;

function init() {
    cont = document.createElement('div');
    cont.id = "cont";
    document.body.appendChild(cont);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w1 / h1, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(90, 90, -200);


    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(camera);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, cont);
    controls.rotateSpeed = 0.8;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    controls.panSpeed = 2.5;
    controls.noZoom = true;
    controls.noPan = true;
    controls.staticMoving = false;

    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    controls.keys = [95, 90, 84];

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();


    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x000000,
        wireframe: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(w1, h1);
    cont.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    generateGeometry();

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(10, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light);

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function generateGeometry() {

    var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper();
    scene.add(axis);

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        var gloom = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('map_pin.png');
        materialr = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: gloom,
            overdraw: true,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(15, 15, 2, 2);

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialr);
        cube.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        cube.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        cube.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        cube.position.normalize();
        cube.position.multiplyScalar(125);

        cube.rotation.x = cube.position.x / Math.PI; //57.38

        cube.rotation.y = 360 / Math.PI * 2;

        objects.push(cube);
        scene.add(cube);

    }

    //earth
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('world.jpg');
    var materials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
        overdraw: true
    });

    var cone = new THREE.SphereGeometry(120, 35, 35);

    var coneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cone, material);

    coneMesh.position.y = 0;
    coneMesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);

    scene.add(coneMesh);


}

init();
animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty unclear what you are looking for; your demo link seems unrelated...

Are you trying to make cubes appear camera normal (always facing the camera)? If so, you'll need logic to re-orient them to re-face the camera anytime the user moves the camera view, as I see you are also setting up the TrackballControls, which actually move the camera, not the scene. This means a user can change the camera view of your scene, and  items you want facing the camera need to be re-orientated. That re-orientation logic needs to be placed inside your render() function.

BTW, to get an object to always face the camera:

- Define it such that when not rotated, it is facing the direction you
  want;
- Place the object into your scene via any method you want,
  including whatever hierarchical rotations or translations you want to use to get them positioned where you want; (Note, they may not be facing
  where you want at this point, but that is okay at this step);
- Request from three.js that it calculate the local to world space
  transformations for your scene. After that, each object's world
  transformation matrix contains the concatenated rotations, and
  translations that transform each object from local space to world
  space.
- Go into each object's local-to-world transform matrix and
  replace the rotation 3x3 matrix components with the identity
  transformation { [1 0 0] [0 1 0] [0 0 1] }. This effectively wipes
  out the rotations in world space, making all the objects you do this
  to always face the camera.